# does PHP header function overwrite htaccess headers?

Tags: php

Setting headers in PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description");
```

Header set in `.htaccess`

```
SetEnvIf Origin ^(https?://.+\.(example|gstatic)\.com(?::\d{1,5})?)$   CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=$1
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin  %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}e   env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

Header merge  Vary "Origin"
```

I'd rather not edit the `.htaccess` file.  Does the PHP `header()` function overwrite?

Comment: I am not sure if it overwrites them but there is this - [header_remove()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php)

Comment: Apache goes first and then php so .htaccess goes first ... and thus will get in the way

Comment: @TOH19 - .htaccess first would be preferable, as you cant overwrite something after PHP finishes.

Comment: Partly depends on the used SAPI. Usually FastCGI/FPM can override all previously set Apache defaults (e.g. Content-Type), or at least accumulate (in the case of Set-Cookie) new headers and thus takes precedence. // Not sure that's very relevant here, when you don't even use any such .htaccess directorives.

Comment: @user892134 - Mabe [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59624/allowing-access-to-an-apache-virtual-host-from-the-local-network-only) will help you

Comment: See the documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header @TOH19, no, .htaccess does not simply "go first".

Answer (score 4):

Without editing your `.htaccess`, it's going to be difficult, but if you allow yourself a small edit, you can make it work.

The [Header Apache2 documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header) says:

> This directive can replace, merge or remove HTTP response headers. The header is modified just after the content handler and output filters are run, allowing outgoing headers to be modified.

So it happens after PHP (a.k.a. *content handler*).

However, if we look at the syntax of the option:

```
Header [condition] add|append|echo|edit|edit*|merge|set|setifempty|unset|note header [[expr=]value [replacement] [early|env=[!]varname|expr=expression]]
```

we see that one of the actions is `setifempty`. This is what you actually want to use. The `set` overwrites the value. `setifempty` sets the value if not already set.

```
Header setifempty Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header setifempty Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Here is that option description:

> *`setifempty`*
>     The request header is set, but only if there is no previous header with this name.

**Note:**

There is a comment about using the `header_remove()` PHP instruction. Only that happens at the time PHP runs which is before the Apache2 `Header` is applied. So it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can't believe how much I thank you.

Been struggling with htaccess regexes and also found no way to access env variables and use them in header outputs.

In the end I'll just use it for the default value with `setifempty` and any complex logic will be implemented in my app.